# How to test redirect style APIs

Tags: java, web-services, unit-testing, tdd, automated-tests

I have an API that I would like to test in an automated fashion. I'm doing it in java at the moment but I think that the problem is language agnostic

**A little bit of context:**

The main idea is to integrate with a payments system in a manner similar to [this demo](https://www.payu.co.za/for-developers/demo/mini-store-demo/product-list/).

**The main flow is something like:**

- You checkout your cart and click a pay button
- Your webapp will initiate a transaction with the payment api and you'd get a reference number. This reference number would now be used as a query parameter for that payment and you'd get redirected to that website.
- After the customer makes the payment, you'd get redirected back to the webapp where you can retrieve the transaction and display the result

My main problem is how do I approach automated integration testing for this type of scenario? The main ideas that I have:

- Use stubbing or mocking for the transaction reference and response. But this is more in line with unit testing than integration testing. I don't mind doing this, but I would want to explore the integration testing first.
- Perhaps I should try some sort of automated form filling. So I would do a curl type request on the redirect url and a curl type post request after inspecting what the redirect website does.
- Use some sort of web testing tool like selenium or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer depends on the goals and scope of your integration test, and also the availability of a suitable platform to use for integration testing. Here are a couple of thoughts that may aid your decision, focussing first on establishing the goals of your tests before making any suggestions on what the appropriate testing tools would be.

(I make the assumption that you don't want to actually use the production version of the payments service when running your tests)

**Testing Integration with a 'Real' Payment Service**: The strongest form of integration test would be one where you actually invoke a real payments service as part of your test, as this would test the code in your application, the code in the payments service, and the communication between the two. However, this requires you to have an always running test version of the payment service available, and the lower the availability of this, the more fragile your tests become.

If the payment service is owned by your team/department/company, this might not be so bad because you have the necessary control to make sure it is always available for testing. However, if it is a vendor system, assuming they control the test version of the service, then you are opening yourself up to fragility issues if they don't effectively maintain that test service to provide a high level of availability (which, in my experience, they generally don't, issues frequently occur like the service doesn't get upgraded often enough, or their support teams don't notice if the service has gone down).

One scenario you may come across is that the vendor may provide a test service that is always running a pre-release version of their software, so that their clients can run tests with new versions of their software before they are released into production and flag any integration issues. If they do, this should definitely influence your decision.

**Testing Integration with a 'Fake' Payment Service**: An alternative is to build a fake version of the service, running in a similar environment to the real service and with the same API, that can be used for integration tests. This can be as simple or as complex as you like, ranging from a very thin service that simply returns a single canned response to each request, to something that can return a range of different responses (success, fail, service not found etc...), depending on what your test goals are.

The upside of this is less fragility - it is likely to have much higher availability because it is under your control, and it will also be much simpler to guarantee the responses from the service you are looking for from your tests. Also, it makes it much simpler to build more intelligent test cases (i.e. a test for how your code responds if the service is unavailable, or if it reports it is under heavy load and cannot process your transaction yet). The downsides are that it is likely to be more work to set up, and you are not exercising the code in the real payments service when you run your unit tests.

**What is the Best Approach to Take to Test the Service?**: This is highly context specific,   however here is what I would consider an ideal approach to testing, based on striking a balance between effectively testing integration with the service, and minimizing the risk of impacting developer productivity through fragile tests.

- If the vendor provides a test version of their service, write a small test suite that verifies you are getting the expected responses from their service, and run this once per day. This will allow the benefits of verifying your own assumptions about the behavior of their service, without introducing fragility to the rest of your tests. The appropriate tool would be the simplest tool for the job (even a shell script which emails you any issues would be absolutely fine here), as long as it is maintainable, at the end of the day these wouldn't be tests developers would be expected to run regularly.
- For my end-to-end test suite  (i.e. one that deploys a test version of the system and tests it end to end), I would build a fake version of the payment service that can be deployed with the test system, and use that for testing. This allows you to test your own system completely end to end, and with a stable payment service endpoint. These end-to-end tests should include scenarios where the service cannot be found, reports a failure, things like that. Given this is end-to-end testing, a tool such as Selenium would be appropriate for tests driven through a web UI.
- For the rest of the automated tests I would mock out calls to the payment service. One very simple approach is to encapsulate all of your calls to the payment service in a single component in your system, which can be easily replaced by a mock version during tests (e.g. using Dependency Injection).

Comment: If writing a test suite of a vendor provided service, I would always recommend wrapping the vendor's service first (to offer only the functionality your app actually needs) and testing through this. JB Rainsberger calls this the "contract tests"